# How to redirect from `/` to `/foo/<id>` using FlowRouter and MeteorJS?

Tags: meteor, flow-router

In my scenario, I want everyone that visits our root URL to be auto-redirected to a url containing a document for collaboration and instant gratification.

Here, the router.coffee code is:

```
FlowRouter.route '/', 
  action: ->
    console.log "I'm home!"
    FlowRouter.go 'myProject'
  name: 'myHome'

FlowRouter.route '/my/:projectId',
  subscriptions: (params) ->
    @register 'currentProject', Meteor.subscribe 'project', params.projectId
  action: ->
    BlazeLayout.render 'myBody'
  name: 'myProject'
```

I want the root URL to redirect to `/my/:projectId` but I'm unsure of how to retrieve the auto-generated `projectId` *and* redirect using with either `FlowRouter.go` *or* `FlowRouter.redirect`.

1. Is this possible?
2. If yes, how?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ toszter  You got answer for question?

Comment: @MariyaJames --- Not yet. I'll self-answer if I discover a solution on my own.

Comment: @toszter: I think you must specify a router if you are using FlowRouter.go or FlowRouter.redirect

Comment: What should be the project ID for users that try to access the root URL (/)?   
Is it a fix one for all or is it based on username/session var/... ?

Comment: @Izack --- I create a baseline project (with a projectId) for each new user. So, when someone registers and they have a persistent session, I would like to redirect them to their project page so they can collaborate with other users.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data may not be available when the route `action` execute,
the best is to **re-route** at the **template level**.

It might be a good idea to use the `Template.[name].onCreated()` function
and put inside it something like the following code:

```
pID = ... // Get the user project ID from wherever you saved it
var params = {projectId: pID}; 

// Set the project URL including the :projectId parameter and re-route the user
FlowRouter.go("myProject", params);
```

Comment: I will give this a shot and see how it fits with my goals.

Comment: To your possible disbelief, I have not tried yet. I imagine based on what I've learned about the Template arch so far, that you're on the right path here and using `FlowRouter.getParam('projectId')` to pull the value is the only bit I'd add. Also, my use of route-level subscriptions is unnecessary here since the Template level would suffice.